How to just simple to insert data(rows) to delta table without strange merge syntax?
I have not found in the documentation how to simply insert data without any dancing with a tambourine.Why complicate the API so much is really unclear.
Maybe someone knows how to use the good old data insertion?
I tried to use merge syntax, but i do not need any matching data(merge condition), i just need to insert data.

This blog explains how to append to a Delta table with PySpark: https://delta.io/blog/2022-11-01-pyspark-save-mode-append-overwrite-error/

You can use the append mode:
(data_frame 
            .write 
            .format("delta") 
            .mode("append") 
            .save(TARGET_LOCATION_PATH))

